# How do you render script tags in flutter dart

Tags: flutter, dart, ads, flutter-web

I have a google and apple ad that I want to use on my new website. However, I am using flutter(dart). In my old site, I used HTML5 and the ads are between  tags. I am adding to the horizontal color bar like the link below.

[horizontal color bar with ad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HapCk.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using flutter web (and not dart web),  then you would have to use first party or third party plugins -

1. [`firebase_admob`](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_admob)

Here's a codelab for reference- [Adding AdMob ads to a Flutter app](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/admob-ads-in-flutter)

And a medium article - [Showing Ads in Flutter app](https://medium.com/@sravanyakatta6/showing-ads-in-flutter-app-f9f1b72eec51)

2. [`ads`](https://pub.dev/packages/ads) (A third party package based on `firebase_admob`)

Comment: It is not a mobile app. It is a website I was adding the ads too. The ads can be added to a regular html, CSS, website. I do not know how to make it work for flutter dart. None of the packages I saw that helps you add html to the website renders script tags.

Comment: As long as you are building a flutter app, you can use this. If you are using dart to inject html (i.e. dart web app) then you could directly use the script by referencing it.